# Is there an easy way to convert Markdown into nice looking html documentation, including navigation?

Tags: html, documentation, markdown, documentation-generation

we are planning to write our software documentation in Markdown, but to provide a clickable webview we need to convert the Markdown documents to a nice looking set of HTML pages.

In our workflow we tend to write the documentation and deliver the documenation together with the sourcecode and binaries to our clients. I found a lot off 1-page convert to html programs, but i am wondering if there is a good converter that takes markdown pages and styling elements and is able to convert that to a workable site, including navigation elements such as sub-pages etc?

Comment: If you would be willing to replace Markdown with reStructuredText (a very similar, if a bit more advanced, syntax), you could use the Sphinx system: http://sphinx.pocoo.org/

Answer (score 0):

Is this an end-user documentation or an API-documentation for developers?

For first case I'd suggest looking at Wiki software with Markdown support.

For second case, you should really mention which programming language.

Comment: It primary end-user documentation like installation instructions/design documentation etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [Gollum](https://github.com/github/gollum).  It's the software that powers Github's wikis.  It converts a git repository of text files into a wiki.

Comment: Gollum seems nice, but we do not store our stuff at GitHub, so it seems the using Gollum is a no go then.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [blog](http://brettterpstra.com/2013/01/23/maintaining-documentation-in-markdown/) that introduces several tools that maintain documentation with Markdown. [ScreenSteps](http://www.screensteps.com/) seems to fit you the best.